# Issues in date conversion

Tags: shell-script, date

I had been trying to add 1 hour to the existing time, as the time stamp is in CST, which I am trying to convert to EST.

```
out_date3=$(ls -lrt out.log | awk '{print $8}')
```

which gives output as 08:45

```
out_date4=$(out_date3 + 01:00)
```

I want the output as 09:45, but the out_date4 is not working.

Comment: EST/CST don't have to do anything with the conversion. The command `date` accepts strings like `date -d '1 hour'`. Please state your problem and edit your question

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with the Central and Eastern US/American timezones, and assuming you have GNU date:

```
TZ=US/Eastern date --date='TZ="US/Central" 08:45'
```

The "outer" (first) TZ environment variable tells date that it should work in the US/Eastern timezone; here, that affects the printing of the time after `date` is done processing the input. The time is then specified using [GNU date's timezone rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Specifying-time-zone-rules.html#Specifying-time-zone-rules), where the double-quotes around the timezone are required. The `--date` specification here says that you'd like to print the time as it exists in the US/Central timezone at 08:45.

The shortest correction to your code would be:

```
out_date4=$(TZ=US/Eastern date --date='TZ="US/Central" '"$out_date3")
```

**Note**

Parsing the output of `ls` will break as soon as out.log becomes last modified more than 6 months ago -- the time format for it in the output from `ls` will switch from "month day hour:minute" to "month day year" and suddenly your awk statement will be sending the *year* instead of the hours & minutes to your out_date3 variable!

More flexibly, and again assuming GNU utilities, use the `stat` command to retrieve the last-modified time, and ask `date` to convert it for you:

```
out_date3=$(stat -c %Y out.log)
out_date4=$(TZ=US/Eastern date --date @"$out_date3")
```

At this point you have the last modification time of out.log in seconds-since-the-epoch in the out_date3 variable. If you want to print it in various formats, `date` will happily do that:

```
date --date @"$out_date3"
date +'%H:%M:%S' --date @"$out_date3"
```